# Dynamically encrypting user configuration settings file

Tags: c#, encryption

I have an application that connects to a database. Is there a way to encrypt the file that contains the connection string along with other settings? The file is quite exposed as the database connection password is stored inside the `user.config` file. The only semi-solution I found was for web applications by adding a `web.config` file, but I'm not sure if this applies the same way. Is there any documentation regarding configuration encryption?

Here's my attempt so far:

**user.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <TimeClock.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="webserver" serializeAs="String">
                <value>test.js.com/</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="timeclockConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
                <value>port=3306;server=localhost;user id=root;password=123456;database=timeclock;convertzerodatetime=True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="screenmode" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
        </TimeClock.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Method:**

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
    ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
string provider = "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider";
ConfigurationSection connStrings = config.GetSection("timeclockConnectionString");

connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
connStrings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to encrypt only the `timeclockConnectionString` and nothing else. Obviously, I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

which probably stems from the `config.GetSection`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "probably"? Can you confirm where the null instance is, please?

Comment: GetSection works on `<configSections><section name="yourName" ...>`  but you are passing GetSection the name of a `<setting` element.  You need to structure your configuration using a configSections if you'd like to use `GetSection`

Comment: Are you using global credentials which you are trying to prevent users from seeing in the config files?  If so, this is a bad approach and you should re-think global credentials.

Comment: @Blorgbeard actually it seems to come from: `connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider)`, but when I change `config.GetSection` to `userSettings/TimeClock.Properties.Settings`, the whole document gets encrypted, which is why I thought the `config.GetSection` was at fault.

Comment: If people have gotten far enough into your system to see the configuration files you have other issues.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey yes, you're right, but this is really not the case here; I'm just merely trying to learn to apply it. But if people did manage to go that far, then yes, I would have other issues.